# ¿Es posible pasar parametros a un controlador mediante la directiva de angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, jade

Quisiera pasar un parámetro de jade al controlador de angular, pero la vista se carga mediante una directiva y me surge la duda de que si es posible pasar unos argumentos.

El jade se carga de la siguiente forma...

```
    mixin mi-cuenta(miCuenta)
        micuenta(class="row")&attributes(attributes)
```

La directiva de angular es la siguiente...

```
   angular.module('cuentas')
          .directive('micuenta', () => {
               return {
                    controller: 'MiCuentaCtrl as miCuentaCtrl',
                    replace: true,
                    template: '../../views/tpl.html',
                    scope: {}
               }
          })
```

en el Jade miCuenta es un JSON con información que quiero agregar al tpl.html pero no se como pasarlo al controlador.